# benchmarking Spring application, multiple small services vs 1 big one performance

Tags: java, spring, performance-testing

I had a discussion about many small Spring services vs 1 big service.

What exactly -performance-wise- will be impacted by these different approaches and how can I benchmark it?

From my understanding, wiring an extra class will only affect the application startup time
and the extra time for the seperate method call is also negligible, so I would opt for many small services, 
as the little performance differences don't weigh up to the clean code.

Comment: Clean code and good design is always easier to improve if the necessity arises. Premature optimization is the root of most evil.